# Number of feasible sequences of stamps

Tags: combinatorics

You have three types of stamps, two different types with a value of $2$ cent and one type with a value of $3$ cent. Now you have to put stamps with a total value of $k$ cent on an envelope. Let $h_k$ be the number of feasible sequences of stamps. Find a closed form for $h_k$.

I tried to write down all the first partitions and came to realize that:

$h_k = h_{k-1}+h_{k-2}+(-1)^k$

This seems like $h_k= F_k + (-1)^k$ with $F_k$ is the k-th Fibonacci number.

But I don't know how to intepret this. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} h_k x^k =\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2(1-x^3)}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What have you tried?  You were given a generating function in a comment.  You can also solve this by recursion.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry for not giving enough details. I just edited.

Comment: You would be correct if the stamps were being placed in a line and the order of the stamps matters. Is that the case? Or should you be counting the number of ways to put stamps on the envelopes without regards to order?

Comment: For example, how many ways are there where $k=6$? If order does not matter, there are 5: {2a, 2a, 2a}, {2a, 2a, 2b}, {2a, 2b, 2b}, {2b, 2b, 2b}, {3, 3}. If order does matter, there are $9=F_{6}+(-1)^6$ sequences, since the sets {2a, 2a, 2b} and {2a, 2b, 2b} can each be ordered in 3 ways.

Answer (score 1):

Your recurrence is correct.  An easier one to justify is to say that to get $k$ cents you can start with $k-2$ and add a $2$ or with $k-3$ and add a $3$.  This says the recurrence is $$h_k=2h_{k-2}+h_{k-3}$$
with starting conditions $h_0=1,h_1=0,h_2=2$.  The classic approach of factoring the characteristic polynomial gives 
$$x^3-2x-1=(x+1)(x^2-x-1)=(x+1)(x-\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2)(x-\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2)$$
The $x+1$ factor gives your $(-1)^k$ and the other factor is the Fibonacci recurrence, so the solution is $a(-1)^k+b(\frac {1+\sqrt 5}2)^k+c(\frac {1-\sqrt 5}2)^k$ and you find $a,b,c$ to match the initial conditions

Comment: Could you please explain why you have that classic approach? Does it come from generating function?

Comment: You can see this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).  It comes from assuming the solution is of the form $r^k$ and plugging that into the recurrence.  $r$ must be a root of the characteristic polynomial.  My recurrence is homogeneous, yours is not because of the $(-1)^k$ term